# I want an image with fixed height and width

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

Here is my site: http://highcatering.wpengine.com/
At the bottom of the site, there is an image of a bride sitting on a couch.

I want that image to keep its height and width. Here's an example: http://lydialavin.com/category/colecciones/

If you see, all the images there don't change size when the screen resolution is reduced.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you don't want the image to be smaller than a specific value. In this case, you should set a min-width pixel value on the element. Let's say 900px:

```
#novia img {
display: block;
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
min-width:900px;
background-position: center center;
}
```

and remove the overflow-x from its container:

```
#novia {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

This way, the background won't get as small as it does now when you see it on smaller screens. Please note, though, that the element will not be perfectly centered as it is now, and some portion of the image will not be shown.

Alternatively, you could give the image a fixed value, but it wouldn't be as effective, as it would probably be too big for smaller screens.

Comment: EXCELENT! :D I added the following statement to the css stylesheet and it worked perfectly: .novia img {min-width:1000px;
} Thanks, @arktoga. :D

Comment: I just detected a problem with this solution. You can see it when you make the window smalller, #novia img sticks out of the body (just scroll right and watch). What can I do? D:

Comment: Hi. Did you remove the overflow from the image's container div (by pasting #novia {overflow-x: hidden;} in your css file)? If you do that, the image won't stick out anymore. 

Edit. Just saw you updated your website, it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Yes!!! I did exactly what you suggested, @arktoga. Thank you very much!! I ended up creating another question for this issue. Problem solved. Thank you, thank you, thank you!! Oh, and I see you already had suggested that on your first comment. :D

Answer (score 0):

This css will fix the width and height of you  bgackground

```
   <style>
   .your-img{
    background:url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   }
  </style>
```